# Heap sort that requires exactly n*log(n) steps

Tags: sorting, heapsort

I know that the upper bound of heap sort is O(n log n), but how do I go about showing an example where it requires exactly n*logn steps? Thanks.

Comment: This depends on what you consider as steps, comparisons, swaps, moves, ... ? For small n, such as n <= 12, you could use a brute force method to try all n! permutations, while counting the number of operations (compares, swaps, moves, ...). It may be possible to start with a sorted array and work backwards through the heap sort algorithm to produce a worst case set of numbers. Since I was able to find some questions about this, I assume that a simple pattern like a reverse ordered set isn't worst case. Note that there are variations of heap sort that would affect the results.

Comment: If only compares are taken into consideration,  would a reverse ordered set be a worst-case?

Comment: Reverse ordered is not worst case. I tested with 10 numbers using a basic heap sort. Reverse ordered data resulted in 46 compares, but this pattern resulted in 54 compares:  0 1 2 5 3 6 7 8 9 4 .

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies things for me.